# Why gRPC does not maintain state between service method calls?

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

Below is my proto service:

```proto
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc IntroduceYourName(HelloRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
  rpc SayHellos (RepeatHelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message RepeatHelloRequest {
  int32 count = 1;
}


// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

This is a simple service, I am trying to set the Name property in the `IntroduceYourName` method and get the Name back in the `SayHellos` method .

However, it doesn't work and Name is null when client calls the `SayHellos` method.

I am working on Net Core 3.1.

Server Implementaion:

```cs
public override Task<Empty> IntroduceYourName(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    this.Name = request.Name;    
    _logger.LogInformation($"Name : {this.Name}");    
    return Task.FromResult(new Empty());
}
    
public override async Task SayHellos(RepeatHelloRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<HelloReply> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
    logger.LogInformation($"SayHellos Name : {this.Name}");
    // _logger.LogInformation("SayRepeatHello called");
    int i = 0;
    while (!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && i++ < request.Count)
    {
        var reply = new HelloReply
        {
            Message = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt") + $" Hello {i} " +this.Name
        };
        await responseStream.WriteAsync(reply);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    if (context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("The client cancelled their request");
    }
}
```

Client code:

```cs
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
Greeter.GreeterClient client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
client.IntroduceYourName(new HelloRequest() { Name = "Foo" });
    
using var stream = client.SayHellos(new RepeatHelloRequest() { Count = 10 }, cancellationToken: ct);
while (await stream.ResponseStream.MoveNext(ct))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + stream.ResponseStream.Current.Message);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide a complete example of your server code. We don't know how you're configuring the server side. If your configuration ends up creating a new instance of whatever type includes the `IntroduceYourName` and `SayHellos` methods, that would explain everything. But we can't tell that from what you've posted.

Comment: I created the service using the grpc service template in VS 2019 .The configuration on the server side is same as that got created by VS 2019.

Comment: That doesn't really help us though, unless you're saying that anyone who would like to help you either has to know the content of that template off by heart, or fire up Visual Studio and go through the same procedure. It would be much more useful if you'd include the code within the post. (Basically, please make it as easy for people to help you as possible.)

Comment: On further investigation found that If I start the server explicitly the issue gets resolved.

eg:  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //
            var server = new Server
            {
                Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterService()) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort(Host, Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
            };
}
Only when I rely on the runtime(generated code from VS 2019 grpc service Template) to configure the grpc server and start the service this issue happens.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me - which is why I asked you to include that template code in your question. I suspect it could easily be fixed by injecting the service as a singleton instead of on a per-request basis, but it's hard to say without seeing the code - and I'm not going to go to the trouble of creating a new project just to find out, when you could easily include the code in the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That's because .net core's IoC container creates new instances for each gRPC GreeterService on server's side. So you should tell the IoC to consider your gRPC service as singleton. Add the following to to server's Startup.cs.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
        services.AddSingleton<GreeterService>();
    }
```

credit goes to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70859587/11736079)