# GRPC service instantiated per call

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I've created a GRPC service host under .NET core 3.1 (using Grpc.AspNetCore v2.30 from https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet). By putting a breakpoint in the "ProxyService" constructor, I can see that the class is instantiated per call - every time a GRPC call is coming from a client, the breakpoint is hit. How do I configure it to always use the same ProxyService instance?

These are the program and Startup classes:

```
    class Program
    {
        const int _port = 23456;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            Console.WriteLine("started - press any key to quit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(o =>
                        {
                            o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                            
                        });
                        options.ListenAnyIP(_port);
                    });
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }

    public class ProxyService : StreamingApi.Protos.StreamingApi.StreamingApiBase
    {
        public ProxyService()
        {
    // gets here with every client call
        }

        public override Task<UpdateResponse> Update(UpdateRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new UpdateResponse());
        }
    }

   class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<ProxyService>();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Your constructor ideally should contain zero-cost logic, like dependencies linkage. Everything else should happen in Update method or before your service start.

Comment: as a start point - i want to measure the number of calls handled and print them to console every 1 second, so i can't add a thread to stay constant and do that in a loop. can this be configured?

Comment: This is shared resource. You should define dependence interface which will hold aggregated value and will be static.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/migration?view=aspnetcore-6.0) you can register your grpc service yourself as a singleton.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();
            services.AddSingleton(new ProxyService());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let me guess why you want to do this:

- You have some heavy-logic inside ProxyService like initialization of some sort;
- You have static variables which you want to share between calls;

To resolve first case you should use either method itself:

```
    public ProxyService(IFooBar foobar)
    {
        this.foobar = foobar;
    }
    public override Task<UpdateResponse> Update(UpdateRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        await this.foobar.InitializeAsync();
        return Task.FromResult(new UpdateResponse());
    }
```

Or some other trigger in your system, like for example "At service start":

```
    public interface IFooBarInitilizer :IHostedService
    {
    }
    public class FooBarInitilizer : IFooBarInitilizer 
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token){ await this.foobar.InitializeAsync(); }
    }

    //in your Configure
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
        services.AddSingleton<IFooBarInitializer, FooBarInitializer>();
        services.AddHostedService(x=> x.GetService<IFooBarInitializer>());
    }
```

For the second case it is even easier, because you just can specify your shared resources through interface dpendency:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
        services.AddSingleton<IFooBarResource, FooBarResource>();
    }

    
public class ProxyService : StreamingApi.Protos.StreamingApi.StreamingApiBase
{
    public ProxyService(IFooBarResource myStaticResource)
    {
        this.myStaticResource = myStaticResource;
    }

    public override Task<UpdateResponse> Update(UpdateRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var somethingGood = this.myStaticResource.GetMeSomethingGood();
        return Task.FromResult(new UpdateResponse());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - looks like the solution i was searching for. just for knowledge - is there a configuration of the service which allows other method for service instantiation other than per call like in WCF?

Comment: I didn't used grpc much, but you can do this just by specifying lifetime dependency in IServiceCollection (per call, per session, per database call, per count of even numbers in current datetime, etc). It will be a lot easier, because of integrated autocomletion in all modern IDE. Read more about IoC and DI to easy manage lifetimes of your business entities.

Comment: thanks - i actually meant for the ProxyService itself which you don't register

Comment: Yeah, I got it, but sadly didn't found any quick references, so this probably means you should do it through DI, atleast it will be more straightforward than some attribute-driven technologies.